# How can I control the expansion direction of a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, web

How can I control the expansion direction of a drop-down list? I've got a long list on the right side of the page that goes off the page because it expands right. Can I make it expand to the left?

Comment: You can try changing the direction to rtl, that may help

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware that's not under the designer's control but under the browser's, at least for "normal" `select` tags. You could always consider using an existing library like jQuery to "roll your own" select implementations (which is more involved, of course), then you can control them at will. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858465/custom-select-dropdowns) for how to do that.