# Bootstrap select option on top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **Boostrap** for my website.

I have added a form in `footer` so that we can change the language, but the select options comes out of the page.

```
    <footer>
      <form role="form" method="GET">
          <div style="float: right">
          <select name="lang" class="form-control" style="height: auto; font-size: 15px; padding: 1px 5px" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="<?php echo $local ?>"><?php echo $localtxt ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $local2 ?>"><?php echo $localtxt2 ?></option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
   </footer>
```

> **What can I do to show the item at the top instead of the bottom ?**

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542687/positioning-the-drop-down-window-of-a-html-select

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622231/how-would-i-control-the-position-of-a-drop-down-select-menu)

Comment: Change `<div style="float: right">` to `<div style="text-align: right">`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Bootstrap has a 'dropup' class which should do what you want. Add the Dropup class to the containing div of the select list:

```
 <div class="dropup">
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
 </div>
```

You can also view the Bootstrap documentation, which shows how to implement the Dropup class:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's a form so I need `<select>` I do not see how to do with a list